# I have bought and will buy another or I'm going to buy

Tags: verbs

Is this sentence ok or should it say I have bought one and will buy another. The first sentence seems to lead the reader into the idea that I have not bought any music yet.

> i'm going to buy the two songs he wants me to memorize for $6 a piece. I already have one purchased and I'll practice it.

Comment: "I have bought one and will buy another"

Comment: I am going to going to going to go to school.